# Hypothesis testing - proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm curious about the procedure on how to execute a hypothesis test for  following hypotheses on a 10% significance level:

[image]

How do I calculate the test variable?

For which levels of Z do I reject the null hypothesis?

Previously I have only worked with null hypothesis stated like this Ho: π = 0.6 (or similarly) and I'm not sure how these kinds of hypotheses tests differ from each other.

Answer (score 2):

The case you are familiar with is called a "two sided" or "two tailed" hypothesis case. This is where you want to know if a parameter is different from a fixed value. The case that you are asking about if a "one sided" or "one tailed" test and here you care about the direction in which it differs. The key difference is that instead of looking at the area under the tail on both sides you only do it on one.

Here are some references that demonstrate this nicely: https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/hypothesis-testing/one-tailed-test-or-two/

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-the-differences-between-one-tailed-and-two-tailed-tests/

Answer (score 1):

## One-Sided Tests for Binomial Success Probability

Suppose you have $n= 100$ binomial trials, with $X =53$ successes.
Because $53 < 60,$ you may wonder whether there is sufficient
evidence to reject $H_0: \pi \ge .6$ against $H_a: \pi < .6$
at the 5% level.

An exact binomial test at the 5% level is not possible (without
randomization) because $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(100, .6)$ has
$P(X \le 52) = 0.0638$ and $P(X \le 51) = 0.0423.$ [Computations in R
where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF:]

```
pbinom(52, 100, .6)
[1] 0.06378918
pbinom(51, 100, .6)
[1] 0.04230142
```

So the critical value for a test at the 4.2% level would be $c = 51.$
That is to say, one would *not* reject $H_0$ with observed $X \le 53.$

For your $X = 53$ observed successes, you have P-value $0.0930 > 0.05.$
This is another way to say you cannot reject $H_0$ at the 5% level.

```
pbinom(53, 100, .6)
[1] 0.09298009
```

[image]

If you want to do this test using a normal approximation, you can proceed
as follows:

$$P(X \le 53) = P(X < 53.5) 
= P\left(\frac{X-n\pi}{\sqrt{n\pi(1-\pi)}} < \frac{-6.5}{4.898979}\right)\\
\approx P(Z < -1.326807) = 0.0923,$$

where $Z$ has the standard normal distribution and the P-value 0.0923 can
be obtained using R, or well-approximated using printed tables of the standard normal CDF.

```
pnorm(-1.326807)
[1] 0.09228627
```

Here is output from Minitab statistical software for this one-sided test (which does not use the normal approximation).

```
Test and CI for One Proportion 

Test of p = 0.6 vs p < 0.6

                                              Exact
Sample   X    N  Sample p  95% Upper Bound  P-Value
1       53  100  0.530000         0.615551    0.093
```

Here is output from thr exact binomial test in R using the procedure `binom.test`.

```
binom.test(53, 100, p=.6, alt="less")

        Exact binomial test

data:  53 and 100
number of successes = 53, number of trials = 100, p-value = 0.09298
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is less than 0.6
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000 0.6155513
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                  0.53
```

---

*Note:* R code for figure:

```
x = 40:80;  pdf = dbinom(x, 100, .6) 
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=2, ylab="PDF", 
   main="PDF of BINOM(100,.6) with Normal Approximation")
 abline(h=0, col="green2"); abline(v=53.5, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 curve(dnorm(x, 60, 4.899), add=T, col="blue", lwd=2)
```